# Passing a script over SSH with arguments

Tags: linux, perl, bash, ssh

I trying to pass a Perl script over SSH that takes arguments. I works fine like this:

```
returnValue=$(ssh myuser$server 'perl -s' < /path/to/my/script)
```

However, if I add some arguments

```
returnValue=$(ssh myuser$server 'perl -s' < '/path/to/my/script -some argument')
```

I get an error "/path/to/my/script -some argument: no such file or directory".

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you tried `$(ssh myuser$server 'perl -s' < /path/to/my/script -some argument)` ?

Comment: Yes, It returns info about perl. "This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi....."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ssh myuser@server perl -s - -some -arguments </path/to/my/script
```

Comment: Looks as if it should work, so +1 from me although I didn't test it.

Answer (score -1):

```
returnValue=$(/path/to/my/script -some argument | ssh myuser$server 'perl -s')
```

Comment: This pipes the output of the script via ssh, not the script itself.